# Is it possible to send a notification to a user when the barometric pressure gets low?

Tags: java, android, if-statement

In my app, I want to send a notification to the user when the barometric pressure gets below a certain number.

I know I have to use an `if` statement, so I have been trying it for a few days now. I tried using the  `if` statement with a `TextView`, which gets the barometric pressure, but this hasn't worked......

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private TextView txt;
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor pressureSensor;
    private SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
            float[] values = sensorEvent.values;
            txt.setText(String.format("%.3f mbar", values[0]));
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txt = findViewById(R.id.barometric);

        //Here is the code I tried... But it is already underlined in red...
        if(barometric < 90.5){

        }

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        pressureSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.settings);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, pressureSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't help you without you giving us more information and posting some code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you share your current code as a [mcve]? This helps us to understand you and your problem better. Without code it still is a bit abstract. For more information see [mcve], [ask] and [How to format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Okay thanks. Sorry, I'm new to this platform :)

Comment: Just wondering, but how do you intend to send the notification? Do you want to literally send a notification to the user, or do you want to show a dialog? You seem to be using a `TextView`, instead of creating a notification and notifying the user.

Comment: I was assuming I would enter the 'send notification' code inside the `if` statement. So that when the pressure falls below the specified number it would send the notification saying "The pressure is low"

Comment: But how do you actually _send_ the notification? That's what I was asking.

Comment: Anyways, I see some stuff in your code: 1. You don't have to assign a temporary variable in the `onSensorChanged` function. Just pass in `sensorEvent.values` instead of setting a variable. 2. What is `barometric`? Where is it defined? Is it a `float` or an `int`?

Comment: I was hoping to take this one step at a time, and first tackle the `if` statement then the notification part of that `if` statement. It's an `int` I really appreciate you help!

Comment: The reason why there's an error is probably because you can't compare a decimal against an integer.

Comment: ohhhh! That makes sense. I'm going to change the barometric, from a `textview` to a decimal component.